# Problematic Microcontroller and VCO

Tags: microcontroller, bit, lpc

I hope your day is going well. I am programming a LPC1768 to send signals to at AD5791 in order to output a given frequency dependent on the output voltage of the AD5791. I have attached the circuit diagram. I have been able to seemingly read and write to the AD5791 from the LPC1768. However, when I connect the VCO to a signal analyzer I see no variation in the peak frequency when I "change" the voltage output of the AD5791. I have been programming using mbed. Below is the code I am currently using. Inputs would be greatly appreciated. I believe the issue may lie in how spi.write is implemented. The AD5791 requires 20-bit words and the LPC1768 can only send 16-bit words max. Also, there is the matter of endianness - but I believe I have solved that as I am reading out what I write to the AD5791 in the order expected.

```
#include "mbed.h"

SPI spi(p5, p6, p7); // mosi, miso, sclk
DigitalOut cs(p8);

int main()
{
spi.format(8,1);
spi.frequency(1000000);
cs=1;

while(1)
{

    cs = 0;
    spi.write(0x10);
    spi.write(0xFF);
    spi.write(0xFF);
    cs = 1;

    cs = 0; 
    int first = spi.write(0x90);
    int second = spi.write(0x00);
    int third = spi.write(0x00);
    cs = 1;

    printf("first register = 0x%X\n", first);
    printf("second register = 0x%X\n", second);
    printf("third register = 0x%X\n", third);
}
```

}`

Comment: Re: the edit: greetings and closings are officially considered noise to be removed - http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989/138636

Comment: Assuming the commands are correct, you're not changing the DAC value (just writing the same value and reading it back) so the output wouldn't change. Also, the documentation (http://wiki.analog.com/resources/quick-start/ad5791) indicates that you need to first initialize the device (e.g 0x200012) to put it in operating mode.

Comment: Ok, great thank you! I will try that and see what happens. Sorry for the delay just returned from travel.

Comment: @Andrew Medico

I modified the code as seen below and have seen no changes. Did I not implement the change correctly?

     #include "mbed.h"
 
SPI spi(p5, p6, p7); // mosi, miso, sclk
DigitalOut cs(p8);
 
int main()
{
    spi.format(8,1);
    spi.frequency(1000000);
    cs=1;
 
    while(1)
    {
 
        cs = 0;
        spi.write(0x20);
        spi.write(0x00);
        spi.write(0x12);
        cs = 1;
        
        cs = 0;
        spi.write(0x1A);
        spi.write(0xAA);
        spi.write(0xAA);
        cs = 1;
    }
}'

Comment: Here is a link to the current code that is still not changing the voltage or frequency of the VCO: https://gist.github.com/tashwoods/84c81f87fa6e0f1b98a2

Comment: I got it to work! https://gist.github.com/tashwoods/84c81f87fa6e0f1b98a2
Thank you again!!!